# how to merge two images iphone with one image variable height

Tags: iphone

I have two images.I want to display like where the first image end the next one should start.

both have same width but the height of the first one is variable .

I am not getting perfect code for it .

please help me 
I am using one above another its displayed as a overlapped ??

Comment: How do you display your images (in UIImageView, draw them directly?..)

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 UIImageView and set their frame in such a way that when the first imageView ends you start the second imageView and in both the imageView set your image. Whatever height it is its gonna set in that imageView Itself....

hAPPY cODING...